# scikit learn imputing values other than NaN

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to impute values for different placeholders which represent empty values in a matrix. For example, I want to impute a value whenever "?" is present in a numpy 2darray.

To this end I create an `Imputer` like so:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
imputer = preprocessing.Imputer(missing_values="?", strategy='mean', axis=0, copy=False)
data = imputer.fit_transform(data)
```

But I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/imputation.pyc in _get_mask(X, value_to_mask)
     27 def _get_mask(X, value_to_mask):
     28     """Compute the boolean mask X == missing_values."""
---> 29     if value_to_mask == "NaN" or np.isnan(value_to_mask):
     30         return np.isnan(X)
     31     else:

NotImplementedError: Not implemented for this type
```

Am I misunderstanding what `missing_values` can be set to?

I was under the impression it could be any string, not just "NaN", which is what the scikit-learn source seems to suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `"integer or string"` really means "either an integer, or the string `'NaN'`". The input to `fit`/`fit_transform` should still be numeric. (The only reason `"NaN"` is passed as a string is that passing `np.nan` can lead to confusing situations because it's not equal to itself, i.e. `np.nan == np.nan` evaluates to `False`.)

Answer (score 0):

which version of sklearn you are using?
Imputer is deprecated from 0.20, instead of it you can use - SimpleImputer

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean', verbose=0)

imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3])           # assume you want to impute 2 columns
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
```